# How to combine git commits

Tags: git

In my local GIT repository, I have the following commits:

A --> B --> C --> D

(Where D is the head)

I would like to combine/squash B and C into a single commit. 
How could I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Use this command:

```
git rebase -i A ;# where A is A's commit hash
```

In the interactive editor, change the the lines, which should look something like this:

```
pick c7787af A
pick f9d9262 B
pick 6c363d0 C
pick 40f657d D
```

To this:

```
pick c7787af A
pick f9d9262 B
squash 6c363d0 C
pick 40f657d D
```

If you'd prefer to abandon C's commit message, but still squash the commit, use this:

```
pick c7787af A
pick f9d9262 B
fixup 6c363d0 C
pick 40f657d D
```

*Never* rebase a branch you've already shared with collaborators. The action changes SHA1 hashes, and results in non-fast-forward updates.

As Jason noted in comments, an alternative syntax is `git rebase -i HEAD~4`. When you're rebasing recent history to squash commits (i.e. when it's easy to count parents back in time), this avoids the trouble of looking up `A`'s hash.

Comment: In addition to @Christopher's answer, you can also use `git rebase -i HEAD~4`, in which 4 is the number of topmost commits you want to change. This saves you from manually entering the hash...